# Strange Rust compilation error

Tags: rust

So... I have following very simple code in my "trial.rs" file.

```
use std::num::Float;

pub struct Vector3< T: Float > {
    pub x: T,
    pub y: T,
    pub z: T
}

impl< T: Float > Vector3< T > {

    pub fn zero() -> Vector3< T > { 
        Vector3 { x: Float::zero(), y: Float::zero(), z: Float::zero() }
    }

}
```

But I am getting following compilation error:

```
trial.rs:12:22: 12:33 error: unresolved name `Float::zero`. Did you mean to call `Vector3::Float::zero`?
trial.rs:12         Vector3 { x: Float::zero(), y: Float::zero(), z: Float::zero() }
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~
trial.rs:12:40: 12:51 error: unresolved name `Float::zero`. Did you mean to call `Vector3::Float::zero`?
trial.rs:12         Vector3 { x: Float::zero(), y: Float::zero(), z: Float::zero() }
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~
trial.rs:12:58: 12:69 error: unresolved name `Float::zero`. Did you mean to call `Vector3::Float::zero`?
trial.rs:12         Vector3 { x: Float::zero(), y: Float::zero(), z: Float::zero() }
```

Any ideas... why??

Edit-1 :: I want generic definition so that I can define things like :

```
pub type Vector3f32 = Vector3<f32>;
pub type Vector3f64 = Vector3<f64>;
```

Comment: Then you want `T::zero()`.

Comment: trial.rs:14:22: 14:29 error: failed to resolve. Use of undeclared module `T`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code compiles on my local version of rust (which I updated this morning from the github repository).

The trait `Zero` has been deprecated recently and `Float::zero()` was created at the same time. Make sure your rust version is up to date.

Comment: rustc 0.13.0-nightly (395901393 2014-11-24 00:46:30 +0000)